# UK transit Visa processing Time

Tags: transit-visas

I have recently applied for a UK transit visa. I had to apply last minute because I was only told on short notice that I needed a transit visa. When I applied they told me it would take 15 working days. I applied for it in the Netherlands. Does anyone know if 15 working days will be when a decision Is made or will that be when my passport is ready for collection?

Comment: Who said you need a UK transit visa? Based on your other questions it appears you do not. Why did you ignore everyone who asked you to clarify your situation?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.